# How to use QMatrix4x4 rotation model in QT OPENGL

Tags: qt, opengl

I am new to OPENGL, I downloaded a project on GIT
https://github.com/schult/qt-gles-demo.git

The program contains a slider that can adjust the Z axis of the model. I continue to add two other sliders to adjust the X and Y axis. The code is as follows:

```
void GlWidget::setModelAngle(int degrees)
{
    m_modelMatrix = QMatrix4x4();
    m_modelMatrix.rotate(degrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    update();
}

void GlWidget::setModelAngleX(int degrees)
{
    m_modelMatrix = QMatrix4x4();
    m_modelMatrix.rotate(degrees, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    update();
}


void GlWidget::setModelAngleY(int degrees)
{
    m_modelMatrix = QMatrix4x4();
    m_modelMatrix.rotate(degrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    update();
}
```

The strange thing is that after adjusting one axis and then adjusting other axes, the model will return to its original state to adjust
E.g
Adjust the X axis to rotate 50°, and then adjust the Y axis. At this time, the X axis will automatically return to zero, and it seems that the adjustment of the X axis is covered

Modify the code again
m_modelMatrix = QMatrix4x4(); is put into the constructor of GlWidget
It seems to be one step closer to success,
However, whether you move the slider to the left or to the right, the model rotates irregularly. I want to move the slider to the left to rotate in one direction, and to move the slider to the right, the model will rotate in the opposite direction.

Simply put, rotate the model like MAYA or Blender, what should I do?

Comment: thats because you set the modelmatrix back to identity in each of this three methods. what you can do is multiplying a rotationmatrix to the modelmatrix

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
void GlWidget::setModelAngle(int degrees)
{
    QMatrix4x4 rotation = QMatrix4x4();
    rotation.rotate(degrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_modelMatrix = m_modelMatrix * rotation;
    update();
}

void GlWidget::setModelAngleX(int degrees)
{
    QMatrix4x4 rotation = QMatrix4x4();
    rotation.rotate(degrees, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_modelMatrix = m_modelMatrix * rotation;
    update();
}


void GlWidget::setModelAngleY(int degrees)
{
    QMatrix4x4 rotation = QMatrix4x4();
    rotation.rotate(degrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    m_modelMatrix = m_modelMatrix * rotation;
    update();
}
```

**The problem:**

In your code you say *m_modelMatrix = QMatrix4x4()*. This sets your matrix back to the identity matrix (all 4 by 4 cells are zero except the diagonal from top left to bottom right is one)
By creating a new matrix (rotation) and multiply it to the modelmatrix you don't loose the information about orientation/position of your model.

The next thing you should understand is the difference between:

```
m_modelMatrix = m_modelMatrix * rotation;
```

and

```
m_modelMatrix = rotation * m_modelMatrix;
```

The matrix multiplications can be seen from right to left. that meens by multiplying multiple matrices it is sometimes a bit confusing what the result will be.

Comment: The text seems rather difficult to describe, I made a video, you can see the difference
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwEOFHP86L4
By the way, I tested your code, and the result is equivalent to this code

void GlWidget::setModelAngle(int degrees)
{
       m_modelMatrix.rotate(degrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
       update();
}


void GlWidget::setModelAngleX(int degrees)
{
       m_modelMatrix.rotate(degrees, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
       update();

}

void GlWidget::setModelAngleY(int degrees)
{
      m_modelMatrix.rotate(degrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      update();
}

Comment: do you mean the behavior, that when the slider is more left, the rotation is faster?

Comment: When I move the slider to the right, the model rotates counterclockwise. When I suddenly move the slider to the left, the model does not immediately rotate in the opposite direction. The model rotates after the slider continues to move a few units to the left.
Actually the operation of the model becomes a bit strange
If you try, you will find

Comment: Can it be, that the slider has the range of [-x, x] ? So when it is in the middle, it is zero. when it is completely on the right it is x and if you move the slider from completely right only one tick to the left, the value is still positive. Because of that the rotation is still counterclockwise.